# What is the name of the format used by Wordpress to store user settings?

Tags: php, string, wordpress, string-formatting

I have searched for a while now and can't seem to find the right answer. Maybe I don't know what to search. What is the name of the format used on this string: `a:1:{i:313;i:1;}` and what is a good PHP parser for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's PHP built-in function [`serialize()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php).

To parse it use [`unserialize()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php).

Comment: Wow, I'm ashamed of the fact that I haven't used this all this time and I haven't even know about it. `unserialize()` solved it for me. Thanks!